# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vcampd.lib'

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I am creating a **Windows Runtime component in VC++** with a very basic functionality, just as a sample. I have also referenced it in my windows phone project. When i am building the component, i get the **lnk1104 error** for **vcampd.lib**. Not sure what went wrong. searched at several places. Got some answers like paths might be wrong, vcampd.lib might not be there, restart VS etc. I checked everything and did not find anything wrong there. Needed help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use C++ AMP? It is not supported on Phone.

Comment: mm.. well.. But that will come into picture only when i will be able to build the component at least.. my first intention is to build the component.. i took the wp8 project just to check if i could refer it or not..